# How to get from CDG T1 to CDG T2D on a short layover

Tags: transit, short-connections, cdg

I am arriving at CDG T1 at 9 am on 30 Sept on Lufthansa and will be taking a flight from CDG T2D at 11 am the same day to Lisbon on Easyjet.

I am rather anxious whether I can make it in time to catch this connecting flight. Is two hours enough time to do this and how do I travel between these two terminals?